# What's the name of this retro Simpsons videogame?

Tags: game-identification

I remember playing this videogame when I was a teen. Does anyone know its name?

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's the NES game [The Simpsons: Bart vs. the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Simpsons:_Bart_vs._the_World)

Here's another screenshot from that game:

[image: Bart vs the world]

Comment: just like bart!